# xcode 13 Assertion failed in function roalloc, file DyldProcessConfig.cpp

Tags: dyld, xcode13

Trying to compile and run an app in xcode13, but dyld assertion failed:

dyld[13967]: Assertion failed: (next < &roBuffer[0x8000]), function roalloc, file
DyldProcessConfig.cpp, line 653.

```
dyld`__abort_with_payload:
    0x100cd74d4 <+0>:  mov    x16, #0x209
    0x100cd74d8 <+4>:  svc    #0x80
->  0x100cd74dc <+8>:  b.lo   0x100cd74fc               ; <+40>
    0x100cd74e0 <+12>: pacibsp 
    0x100cd74e4 <+16>: stp    x29, x30, [sp, #-0x10]!
    0x100cd74e8 <+20>: mov    x29, sp
    0x100cd74ec <+24>: bl     0x100c8ed68               ; cerror_nocancel
    0x100cd74f0 <+28>: mov    sp, x29
    0x100cd74f4 <+32>: ldp    x29, x30, [sp], #0x10
    0x100cd74f8 <+36>: retab  
    0x100cd74fc <+40>: ret
```

Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

The environment is:
macOS12.0.1, xcode13.1

Anyone know something about this roalloc function and DyldProcessConfig.cpp? I google it but find nothing.